# intersection cohomology and etale cohomology

Tags: intersection-cohomology, etale-cohomology, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Hello,

Can someone explain or give a reference on the comparison between intersection cohomology and l-adic etale cohomology of a variety over a field of characteristic zero?

Thanks!

Comment: The only general link I know is the fact that intersection cohomology with coefficients in ${\bf Q}_l$ is isomorphic to étale cohomology if the variety is non-singular. Otherwise, there is no link: the first is the cohomology of the intersection complex IC, which only coincides with the constant system ${\bf Q}_l$ if the variety is non-singular. See any introduction to perverse sheaves, for instance the introduction by Migliorini and de Cataldo (see http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2009-46-04/S0273-0979-09-01260-9/S0273-0979-09-01260-9.pdf) or the original article "BBD" (see ref. in intro.)

Comment: Intersection cohomology (in the context of the etale topology) generalizes the usual l-adic cohomology. With the appropriate choice of the perversity, intersection cohomology gives the usual l-adic cohomology, with or without compact support.

Comment: @anon: I was implicitly referring to middle perversity.